# Attributes showing product´s actual price

Tags: attributes, price, dropdown-attribute, price-rules, magento1.9.0.1

I would like to create a product, that is customizable by weight (for example: loose tea).
The variants of the attribute "weight"(e.g. 100 grams / 500 grams etc.), should show the weight´s actual price and not the additive price as it would be common for configurable products.

Here you will find two examples (I´m sorry, only in German - just choose the Drop Down attribute "Gewicht" on the first page / Radio Buttons on the second):

http://www.krauterie.de/kraeuter-fuer-pferde/gelenke-pferd/spat-arthrose-kraeuter1.html
[--Choose Attribute "Gewicht" at Drop Down]

http://www.meine-teemischung.de/tee-blueten-8/kamille-flores-chamomillae-172
[---Radio Buttons!]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you need `to use custom option which is provide this type of  functionality`  and also can `use configurable product but that time you need to customization on UI`

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/creating-a-configurable-product

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/create-custom-variants-and-options-of-a-product

**Use custom options if:**

- You have a small catalog and are looking for a quick way to create
  customizable products.
- You don't need to manage inventory.
- You have a small catalog and want an easy way to offer product
  variations.
- The options are applied after the product is ordered, such as custom
  embroidery on a tee shirt.

**Use a configurable product options if:**

- You manage a large catalog of products with many variations.
- You want to manage inventory separately for each variation.
- You want each variation to have its own product page.

Comment: Dear Amit Bera, many thanks for your quick answer. I created custom options ("weight") for my product as it is shown at your link to the Magento Knowledge-Base. Unfortunately still a base price for the product is needed - my product must get its complete price only from the one attribute´s variant. Example: You offer camomile tea - open the product page in front-end - it still has no final price and gets the price only by selecting the weight/amount you need. I really hope, you can still help me. Many thanks for your efforts in forward. With kind regards, Max W.

Comment: Amit Bera, I have the beginning of a message from you in my inbox, but I can only read the first few words "Magento by default calculate the "Final Price" as Base price + Addon price (custom option). No ab..." and the link does not lead to this message, so please post it again! Please also note the a bit better explained new version of my question: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/38557/how-to-create-a-product-that-gets-its-complete-price-by-selecting-only-one-attri In the first link you can see that it must be possible to create the price without a base price only by one attribute